# Publish command for ASP.NET Core project only includes DLL files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dotnet-cli

I'm trying to **publish** an **ASP.NET Core 1.0** project, in order to be able to deploy it to Azure (or other hosting environments) later on.

My folder structure is as follows (not sure if it matters):

```
|_Root
  |_Foo
    |_Bar -> contains project.json
```

From the **root** folder I run the publish command like so:

**`dotnet publish Foo/Bar -o artifacts\FooBarOutput --configuration Release`**

This creates a folder with output from the `publish` command, but it **only contains assemblies** (DLL files) and a folder called `refs` containing referenced assemblies.

My question is: how do I create a complete publish package, including all static resources such as HTML, JavaScript, CSS, configuration files, etc?

Am I missing something in my `project.json` file, or some parameters for the `publish` command? I must be missing something, but I guess there must be some way to specify that the `src` folder etc should be included in the output?

My `project.json` file looks like the following:

```
{
  "title": "My Web App",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true, 
    "compile": {
      "exclude": [ "bin/**", "obj/**", "node_modules/" ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "System.IO.FileSystem": "4.0.1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0"
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls=http://*:8000/"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `publishOptions` section in your project.json like this :

```
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
        "wwwroot",
        "Views",
        "web.config",
        "appsettings.json",
        "appsettings.*.json",
        "..."
    ]
}
```

Comment: Aha, I knew I had to be missing something like that. :) Thanks, I'll try it out right away!